# Creating metro style winform in windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to design a metro styled winform in visual studio 10 or visual studio 11 on windows 7? If so, where can I find info on how to do it? I have already found some links, like 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380
But I don't get the  Windows Metro style.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you read that article? It says quite clearly that it's using Visual Studio 11 beta for Window 8 SDK.

Comment: Yes, right after I posted this I realized that it also needed to be done in Windows 8 beta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strict Metro UI apps are Windows 8 only, and they require WinRT.

But if you want to simulate the Metro style in Windows 7 and Windows Forms, you can use third party controls (or develop your own), such as the Telerik ones,

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx

Answer (score 119):

Or just using my framework :)

https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui

Updated fork: https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui it provides Metro style for WinForms applications. It works with NET Framework 2.0 and above.

Comment: Link is broken; use https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try WPF development using Elysium library on codeplex - http://elysium.codeplex.com/.

You can find the installation guide and sample implementation code here
http://bizvise.com/2012/09/27/how-to-create-metro-style-window-on-wpf-using-elysium/

Answer (score 1):

There is another third party library to create Metro Styles applications in Windows 7 using Windows Forms. Check [Devcomponents](http://devcomponents.com/blog/?tag=metro).

Answer (score 0):

You can make Metro styled apps with Visual Studio 11 Beta for Windows 8, with the correct SDK. Reading the article *you* linked gave me [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx) to download everything you need.

Download that, follow the tutorial you've already got.

Update:
As @bobsmith833 mentions, Metro and WinForms are different frameworks entirely. There's no way to use the two together. You'll have to go for Windows 8 and the Metro framwork if you want to make these apps.

Comment: I think you're confusing concepts here. Metro is not "supported" for WinForms or WPF, it is a completely different framework. WinForms and WPF run in the "desktop" portion of Win8, while Metro apps run in the "Metro style app" portion. The only thing Metro and WPF really have in common is that they both (potentially) may use XAML as their design language.

Comment: I see. My mistake, I saw XAML and jumped to WPF.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite confusing. The XAML used in Metro actually bears more resemblance to Silverlight than WPF, in that lots of nice features such as dynamically selecting a DataTemplate based on model type and declaring a Visibility=Hidden value are missing. However, it is also definitely not Silverlight. It is its own beast!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Metro style apps do not currently work on Windows 7.

I have also heard that it is unlikely there will ever be a version of Metro for Win 7 - I think their operation goes too far to the heart of Windows for that to be practical.

So you'll have to bite the bullet and get the Win 8 preview I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the metro design, not the actual metro framework, [devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) has the components you need.

Answer (score 0):

Easily. If you use Windows Forms, go to Solution Explorer and right-click the solution. Select from the menu the NuGet controler or sth like that. The program will load widgets, from which you can choose one depending on your needs and install it. For a Metro design, I use Metro UI. Just write the key words in the search panel. After installation, add the controls to the toolbox. For more info, search Foxlearn's video. ;-)