# Items set to Visible=false are being shown when tabbing inside TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro

So I am making a new project and I am using a theme for the first time (MetroSet). I currently have 30 buttons in a `MetroSetTabControl` tab all set to Visible=false. When I first launch the application, all is good. If I tab over to the 2nd tab, then go back to the first, all buttons are now shown.

Any ideas why its doing this, or how to resolve?

See GIF below

[image: GIF added to show what I am talking about]

**Theme Set Being used:** https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI

**Steps to replicate:**

1. Create a new Windows Forms Application project in Visual Studio and install [MetroSet_UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroSet_UI/) via nuget:

   ```
   Install-Package MetroSet_UI
   ```
2. Create a [`MetroSetForm`](https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI/blob/master/MetroSet%20UI/Forms/MetroSetForm.cs) and insert a [`MetroSetTabControl`](https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI/blob/master/MetroSet%20UI/Controls/MetroSetTabControl.cs) with 2 tabs
3. Add 1 or more [`MetroSetButton`](https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI/blob/master/MetroSet%20UI/Controls/MetroSetButton.cs) to index 0 and set them all to `Visible=false`.
4. Debug application starting on index 0
5. Toggle to index 1 and back to 0

Comment: Is it possible these buttons are being instantiated again when you change the tabs?

Comment: @dedecos thats what I am assuming is happening, but I have no idea why, or how

Comment: Without further information it will be hard to help you.

Comment: You could try to set a data breakpoint on write of one of these buttons visible variable to get a possible code that is changing its value.

Comment: @dedecos not sure what other information you require. I have no back-end code (other then the designer, that I have not touched by hand)

Comment: @dbc I think I added what you are looking for. I have no other code then the designer at the moment, and that was all done using the toolbox (nothing touched within the designer code itself)

Comment: I can't find many questions about your framework here.  There are some questions about https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework.  For more see [Creating metro style winform in windows 7 using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9939070).

Comment: Can you specify exactly what [controls](https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI/tree/master/MetroSet%20UI/Controls) you are adding?  E.g. is `TabControl` actually [`MetroSet_UI.Controls.MetroSetTabControl`](https://github.com/N-a-r-w-i-n/MetroSet-UI/blob/master/MetroSet%20UI/Controls/MetroSetTabControl.cs)?

Comment: @dbc Ya that looks correct. The controls I am using are MetroSetButton, MetroSetTabControl and MetroSetForm (for the form style itself). As a current work-around, I just added a function to check everytime it changes tabs, what is should be set to. At this point, I just want to know why its acting silly.